# Android app : Issue with ToolBar options, when opened pdf file with qoppa library

Tags: android, pdf, itext

[image: Issue relavent screenshots for better idea]

- Actually in my android app, opening pdf document using qoppa library. Code is as below...

  ```
  private void openDocumentUsingQoppa() {

  StandardFontTF.mAssetMgr = getAssets(); //assets;
  try {
      Constants.strFilePath = Constants.FOLDER_PATH + Constants.FILE_NAME;
      pdfDoc = new PDFDocument(Constants.strFilePath, null);
      PDFDocument.setKey("abcde"); //, this
  } catch (PDFException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  viewer = new QPDFNotesView(this);

  viewer.setActivity(this);
  Button sign = new Button(getApplicationContext());
  sign.setText("Sign");
  sign.setTextColor(Color.RED);
  sign.setTextSize(16);
  sign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // logic to continue.
      }
  });
  viewer.getToolbar().addView(sign, 0);

  viewer.getToolbar().removeViews(13, 3);
  viewer.getToolbar().removeViewAt(17);
  viewer.getToolbar().removeViewAt(20);

  setContentView(viewer);
  if(pdfDoc != null) viewer.setDocument(pdfDoc);
  ```

  }
- Now document is opened, and in bottom toolbar options left to arrow marks are working, but when i click on "write" which is right side of arrows giving me exception.

  - Please find the attachments for more information.

Comment: If you use qoppa, why do you tag this question as itext? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Actually using both qoppa and Itext in pdf document generation and for viewer. To add here no tag for "qoppa"

Comment: Now there is a `qoppa` tag.